# Is $\tan x$ continuous at $0$? If so, how can I prove using $\epsilon$ and $\delta$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am new to $\epsilon - \delta$ proof.

It seems like that $\tan x$ is continuous at 0, since $\tan x=0$ and right and left limits of $\tan x$ is $0$.

However, how can I show that this is continuous at $0$ using $\epsilon - \delta$ proof?

Comment: What definition of the tangent function are you using?

Comment: One definition is $\tan x = \sin x/\cos x$, and standard arguments can be used building on the continuity of those two other trigonometric functions.

Comment: is that because 1/cosx is continuous and sinx is continuous  and thus sinx/cosx is continuous?

Comment: (at a neighborhood around $x = 0$...)

Comment: Yes, you should prove a theorem that the ratio (and sum, difference, and product) of continuous functions is continuous.

Answer (score 2):

There are better ways to do this, as discussed in the comments, but if you insist on going the $\epsilon - \delta$ way here's one method to show that $\tan x$ is continuous at $0$.

Note that

$|\sin x| \le |x|$, and $|\cos x| \ge 1 - x^2/2$

This implies that

$|\tan x - 0| \le \frac{|x|}{1 - x^2/2} \le \frac{\delta}{1 - \delta^2/2}$

Taking $\delta(\epsilon) = \frac{\sqrt{2 \epsilon^2 + 1} - 1}{\epsilon}$, the conclusion follows.

Comment: Are you assuming that x is sufficiently small?

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both continuous at $x_0$ and $g(x_0) \neq 0$, then $\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}$ is continuous at $x_0$.  To sketch an $\epsilon - \delta$ proof, let $f(x_0)=F, g(x_0)=G.$  I claim $\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}$ is continuous at $x_0$ with value $\frac FG$  If you give me an $\epsilon$ and ask for a $\delta$,  I give you $\epsilon_f=\frac \epsilon {2G}$ and ask for $\delta_f$ and $\epsilon_g=\frac {F\epsilon}{2G^2}$ and ask for $\delta_g$.  I claim that $\min(\delta_f,\delta_g)$ will be an appropriate $\delta$.  If you follow the error analysis through, you will see it.  You might actually have to shrink $\delta_g$ a bit because of the inverse, but I left it this way to show the derivative.